# where to put the logic to decide whether getting data from Remote or from Local in Repository Pattern?

Tags: flutter, dart, repository-pattern

I want to implement Repository pattern on my Flutter app.

let say I create an interface to get book List like this

```
abstract class BookRepository {

   Future<List<Book>> getBookList();

}
```

I want to display book list on my Home Page. if it has internet connection, then retrieve data from the Remote (using Dio), otherwise get data from Local storage (using Hive)

so I create 2 classes that implement the interface above.

the first one is for remote repository

```
class BookRemoteRepository implements BookRepository {

    @override
    Future<List<Book>> getBookList() async {

        List<Book> booksFromServer = await dio.get();  // Using Dio
        return booksFromServer;
    }

}
```

the second one is for Local repository

```
class BookLocalRepository implements BookRepository {

    @override
    Future<List<Book>> getBookList() async {

        List<Book> booksFromLocalStorage = await Hive.get(); // Using Hive
        return booksFromLocalStorage;
    }

}
```

I am confused where to put the logic to decide whether getting data from Remote or from Local

currently what Implement is like this

```
class HomePageController {


  late BookRepository _bookRepository;


  Future<List<Book>> retrieveBooks() async {

      if (hasInternetConnection) {
         _bookRepository = BookRemoteRepository();
      } else {
         _bookRepository = BookLocalRepository();
      }

      return await _bookRepository.getBookList();

  }


}
```

that `retrieveBooks` method in `HomePageController` will be called if the user press a button on the UI.

do I implement the repository pattern correctly? do I need to make a separated class just to decide ? I am confused where to put the logic to decide whether getting data from Remote or from Local

Answer (score 0):

You should check DDD Pattern, not sure if it is the same as repository pattern but here you can see the logic behind repositories.

https://resocoder.com/2020/03/09/flutter-firebase-ddd-course-1-domain-driven-design-principles/

https://github.com/mhadaily/flutter-architecture-ddd/tree/master/enterprise/lib/catalog/infrastructure

So, the idea is to have datasources (hive, api, json, etc) and in the repository have the logic to decide which datasource you are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

The remote/local/cache abilities are "strategies" by which you choose to fulfill your repository's purpose, in runtime, according to network conditions.

You can solve this problem using the ["strategy" pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy). Pass an instance implementing the strategy into the "context" - the domain object (`BookRepository`). The "context" should not be aware of the strategy and just execute the interface methods, in your case `get()`.

But the solution above is not good enough because it assumes the strategy selection was made once and early in the application's lifecycle. In your case it's in your best interest to delay the strategy selection as much as possible, and to always be able to switch between strategies.
In addition, the strategy selection process itself is domain-agnostic meaning that the choice whether to fetch the data from remote or local should not be aware of the domain - it can be books or notes or drawings or whatever. It should only care about internet connection. Lastly you don't want to repeat yourself duplicating this code in different domains.

For those reasons, the strategy selection mechanism and the strategies' themselves should be implemented in separate classes that are domain-agnostic.

For example you can implement a `CachedRepository<T>` that implements `Future<T> get`. This cached repository would hold references to both `Hive`'s interface and `Remote`'s interface and perform the fallback logic inside.

The above suggestion was inspired from the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805942/4115109)